# Can I use 2 different Appsflyer account in a ios application?

Tags: ios, appsflyer-ios-sdk

As the title and due to my company marketing plan, if I use 2 different Appsflyer accounts (2 different appsflyer dev key) can my app working normally in tracking user events? Or they will overwrite each other?

Does someone do it before?

Comment: any reason why do you want 2 dashboards?

Comment: @MaximShoustin It's about marketing plan. Marketing team want to use separate account for 2 teams. And they asked me to find a way to use 2 dashboards at the same time. I have no idea why they want to do it. But thank you for your answer below.

Comment: I know for Android, for example, you can use the `channel` a.e. instead `com.my.app` - `com.my.app-MyChannel1` - both dashboards will be related to the same app. It's for Out-of-Store apps, mostly in China.

Comment: @MaximShoustin You mean Out-of-Store apps is all the apps using enterprise certificate for signing? If it's true, it's not what I want because we using for App Store app.. Look like in iOS I cannot use the channel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Short answer*

> (2 different appsflyer dev key) can my app working normally in tracking user events?

No

> Or they will overwrite each other?

Yes

*Detailed answer:*

The `AppsFlyer` SDK is a singleton and you can run one instance only during app lifecycle. Creating multiple instances can lead to unexpected behaviors like uninstalls, attribution re-engagement and so on.